# `ModuleNotFoundError` with custom Python project layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, project-layout

I'm trying to setup a python project following a structure that is shown [here](https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/#application-with-internal-packages). In my case, I have:

```
.
└── helloworld/
    ├── hello/
    │   ├── hello.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── world/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── utils.py
        └── world.py
```

The contents of `hello/hello.py`:

```
from helloworld.world.utils import get_number

def say_hello(greeting):
    return (greeting.upper(), get_number())
```

Contents of `world/world.py`:

```
def say_world(place):
    return place.upper()
```

Contents of `world/utils.py`:

```
from random import randrange

def get_number():
        return randrange(10)
```

And in `main.py` I simply have an import so far:

```
from hello.hello import say_hello
```

I think I have all the necessary `__init__.py` files, including in the project folder, which should make it to be treated like a module, but I can't figure how to workaround the error I'm getting with the imports:

```
$ python3 helloworld/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from hello.hello import say_hello
  File "/home/foobar/proj-layout/helloworld/hello/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from helloworld.world.utils import get_number
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helloworld'
```

What am I doing wrong here, and how can a project structure like this one work with `import helloworld`?

I don't want to have this project installed for now, so something like `setup.py -e` would not be the best solution.

I know similar questions have been asked before, but none of the ones I could find seemed to work in my case. Maybe there's something on SO that I have overseen, but I honestly couldn't find it before posting this question.

Comment: try relative imports `from ..world.utils import get_number`

Comment: Your imports are not consistent, in main.py you should import helloworld.hello.hello or in hello.py you should import world.utils.
Also you might change your PYTHONPATH setting the root folder (depends on how you will manage the imports or your protect).

Answer (score 1):

The imports within an uninstalled module (you dont want to use `pip install -e`) are relative. Try these changes:

```
from ..helloworld.world.utils import get_number

def say_hello(greeting):
    return (greeting.upper(), get_number())
```

Note the `..` in front of the import. You can use your IDE's auto complete to find the right amount and to navigate within the modules.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your `main.py`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

# add the parent directory helloworld to the sys.path
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parents[0]))

from hello.hello import say_hello

print(say_hello('Hello world!'))
```

A cleaner solution would be to import `absolute_import` from `__future__`. So for your `main.py` it would be

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from hello.hello import say_hello

print(say_hello('hello world'))
```

and for your `hello/hello.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from world.utils import get_number

def say_hello(greeting):
    return (greeting.upper(), get_number())
```